# can' t use keepassxc with Brave/Vivaldi and firejail

Tags: firejail, keepassxc

I have Fedora 38 Cinnamon system. Since a couple of weeks I can’t use Keepassxc with Brave/Vivaldi. I also use firejail for extra security. After adding KeePassXC-Browser to Brave/Vivaldi, I had an error from the add-on:

Cannot connect to KeePassXC. Check that browser integration is enabled in KeePassXC settings.

The browser integration is enabled. I guess that the error occurs because I am running Brave/Vivaldi under firejail. I used the command sudo firecfg for firejail

I am having problems running KeePassXC under firejail  Does anyone have any tips about running these three together?

Any help would be appreciated.